# How would you do a removeIf on a list or set for primitives in eclipse collections?

Tags: java, eclipse-collections

On regular java collections it's possible to remove an element given an input `Predicate`.

`persons.removeIf(person -> person.isMale());`

In eclipse collections it seems possible to do this as long as the collection being used extends `Iterable<T>`.

For primitive collections that extend `PrimitiveIterable`, there doesn't seem to be a method provided to do the same. Is it not supported? If not, why?

EDIT:
I should add that I'm looking for a method that removes an item in-place without creating a new set, as [reject](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/collection/primitive/MutableIntCollection.html#reject-org.eclipse.collections.api.block.predicate.primitive.IntPredicate-) does.

Comment: Well, `removeIf` didn't get added onto the interface until Java 8...

Comment: *"Is it not supported?"* **Read the documentation**. Seems you're looking for [`MutableIntCollection.reject​(IntPredicate predicate)`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/collection/primitive/MutableIntCollection.html#reject-org.eclipse.collections.api.block.predicate.primitive.IntPredicate-), or one of it's cousins. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: I did look at the documentation. Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough, I want something that removes an element in place. ```reject``` returns a new set with the elements that did not match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `removeIf` doesn't exist for mutable primitive collections in Eclipse Collections today.  It makes sense to add, as it has been on the mutable object collections since at least [version 2.0](http://www.goldmansachs.com/gs-collections/javadoc/2.0.0/com/gs/collections/api/collection/MutableCollection.html#removeIf(com.gs.collections.api.block.predicate.Predicate)) which was released in August 2012.  I just started working on it.  It can be added as a default method so should hopefully be available in the 9.1 release.

**Update:** The method [`removeIf`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/collection/primitive/MutableIntCollection.html#removeIf-org.eclipse.collections.api.block.predicate.primitive.IntPredicate-) was added to mutable primitive collections in the [9.1 release of Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/releases/tag/9.1.0).

Comment: Pull request for this has been merged so will be in next release: https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/pull/377